# Is $p >a$ a condition of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Web search: $p$ is a prime, $a$ is any integer for which $a^p-a$ is a multiple of $p$.
My research: I found that if $p$ is smaller than a then the remainder of $a^p/p$ is not going to be a which is contradict to the theorem.
Examples:
$$p=2,a=17$$
$$17/2=8+1/2$$
$$17^2/2=144+1/2$$
Contradiction shown.

Comment: The theorem  that $17^2 - 17$ will be a multiple of $2$.  And it is.  $17^2 - 17= 289-17 = 272$ which *is* divisible by $2$.  That *does* mean that $17^2 \div 2$ and $17\div 2$ will have the same remainder.  And they *do*; that remainder is $1$.  But it doesn't mean the remainder will *be* $17$.  It only means that t the remainder will be *congruent* to $17$.  And it is.  The remainder of $17^2 \div 2$ is $1$.  And $1 \equiv 17\pmod 2$.

Comment: $x\equiv a\pmod{\!p}\!\iff\! p\mid x-a\,$ is not the same as $\,x \bmod p = a$. It's the same as $\,x\bmod p = a\bmod p,\,$ i.e. they're congruent $\!\iff\!$ they have equal remainders. See the linked dupe for more on the relationship between the congruence relation and mod (remainder) operation, and related topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem says that $a^p\equiv a \pmod p$.  That means $a^p \div p$ and $a\div p$ will have the same remainder.  It does *NOT* mean that the remainder will *BE* $a$.  Just that $a^p$ and $a$ will have the same remainder.

And if $p < a$ then of course the remainder will not be $a$ because the *remainder*, $r$, by definition is *less* than $p$ so $r < p < a$.  *BUT* it will be true that $a = r + k\cdot p$ for some (in this case positive) integer $k$.  (or in other words that $p$ will divide $a - r$.)

Your examples are not contradiction. The remainder of $17\div 2$ is $1$.  And the remainder of $17^2 \div 2$ is *also* $1$.  And so $17^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$  and $17\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $17^2 \equiv 17 \pmod 2$ and $17^2 - 17$ is a multiple of $2$.

Everything behaves *exactly* as the theorem predicted.

......

A more illustrative example might be a larger prime.  $p = 7$ and $a=11$ say.

$11= 1\times 7 + 4$ so the remainder is $4$.

And $11^7 = 19487171= 2783881\times 7 + 4$ also has a remainder of $4$.

And that's *confirms* the theorem and $4 +7 = 11$ and $11 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ so

$11^7 \equiv 11 \pmod 7$ and

$11^7 -11= 19487171 - 11 = 19487160 = 2783880 \times 7$.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such condition in Fermat's little Theorem. The example you considered is $p=2, a=17$. This works perfectly fine: $a^p-a=17^2-17=272$, which is a multiple of $p=2$. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: $17^2-17$ is the difference of two odds so is even - you don't need to calculate its value to see that [but if you do it's easier to note it $= 17(17-1) = 17(8\cdot\color{#c00}2)]\ \ $

Comment: So when 17^2/2~=1mod2 or 17 mod 2